# Reusable background thread in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to create a reusable background thread to queue a number of tasks that require access to a singleton resource. The thread should be created at the start of the program and a message will be sent whenever it is required to complete a task. At first I was trying to use a worker thread, as the background thread doesn't have a UI, but then I noticed that only UI threads have message pumps. Unfortunately, `PostThreadMessage` always returns `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID`, but I am sure the thread has been created correctly.

1. Is it a good choice to use a UI thread rather than a worker thread?
2. Why isn't my `PostThreadMessage` being received?

**UPDATE**: By looking at the output messages, I now know that the message isn't being received because the thread is killed

Sample code

```
DWORD deviceControllerThread;

void post(){
    BOOL res=PostThreadMessage(deviceControllerthread,ControllerThread, ENROLLMENT_BEGIN, (WPARAM) myDataPointer, 0);
    ...
}

void MFC_Init(){
    CWinThread* thread=AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(MFC_thread), THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0);
    deviceControllerThread=thread->m_nThreadID;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your thread initializes it just needs to call PeekMessage to "create" a message queue.  Then the other thread can post messages to it via PostThreadMessage.  Also, that error code of INVALID_THREAD_ID is a symptom that your worker thread has actually exited (or was never created).  Make sure you have sufficient debug spew or logging to validate that the worker thread got created and didn't prematurely exit. Also, make sure you are checking the return code for AfxBeginThread and that m_nThreadID is valid (because I'm assume you initialized it to zero).

I do similar threading exercises all the time.  I've moved away from using the message queue and onto using my own eventing and queues for finer control.

If you don't need to guarantee ordering of work items, then another idea is to just use the Windows "thread pool" to do the work for you.

Below is an OUTLINE of how I usually structure a thread class in C++.  It's just something I whipped together based on existing projects and is NOT production code.  But it should demonstrate some concepts of how to manage a thread lifetime.

```
// CList is any generic "array" or "list" class (you can use std::list, CAtlArray, CSimpleArray, etc...)

// ThreadMessage is your data structure for holding data to indicate to the thread what to do
// e.g.
// struct ThreadMessage
//{
//    enum type; // YOUR_CODE_TO_QUIT=0, WORK_MESSAGE=1, etc...
//    workdata data;
//};

class CMyThread
{
private:
     CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;  // lock such that m_queue is thread safe, can be replaced with CComAutoCriticalSection or equivalent
     bool m_fNeedToExit;     // signals to the worker thread that it is time to exit
     HANDLE m_hEvent;        // For waking up the worker thread to tell it a new message is available
     HANDLE m_hThread;       // handle to worker thread
     HANDLE m_hStartEvent;   // For the worker thread to signal back to the parent thread that is has finished initializing
     bool m_fStarted;        // Has Start() been called
     DWORD m_dwThread;       // threadID
     CList<ThreadMessage> m_queue; // generic "array" of work items.  Can be replaced with any list-type data structure

public:
     CMyThread()
     {
          InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
     }

     ~CMyThread()
     {
         Stop();
         DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
     }

     HRESULT Start()
     {
         if (m_fStarted)
            return S_FALSE;

         // todo - check all return codes from the Create functions!

         m_hEvent = CreateEvent(0,0,0,0);  // unsignalled, unnamed, auto-reset event
         m_hStartEvent = CreateEvent(0,0,0,0);  // unsignalled, unnamed, auto-reset event
         m_hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CMyThread::ThreadProc, this, 0, &m_dwThreadID);

         // PUT YOUR THREAD INITIALIZATION CODE HERE


         // wait for the thread to intialize (you don't have to call this next line if the thread doesn't have any initialization to wait for */
         WaitForSingleObject(m_hStartEvent, INFINITE);

         m_fStarted = true;

         return S_OK;

     }

     HRESULT Stop()
     {

         if (m_hThread)
         {
             m_fNeedToExit = true;
             ThreadMessage quitmessage;
             quitmessage.type = YOUR_CODE_TO_QUIT;
             SendMessageToThread(&quitmessage);

             // in a debug build, you may want to wait for X seconds and show an error message if the worker thread appears hung

             WaitForSingleObject(m_hThread, INFINITE);

             // cleanup
             CloseHandle(m_hThread); m_hThread = NULL;
             CloseHandle(m_hStartEvent); m_hStartEvent = NULL;
             CloseHandle(m_hEvent); m_hEvent= NULL;
             m_fStarted = true;
             m_dwThread = 0;
             m_queue.empty();
         }

         return S_OK;
     }

     HRESULT SendMessageToThread(Message* pMsg)
     {
         if (m_fStarted == false)
             return E_FAIL;

         EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
             m_queue.enque(*pMsg); //push message onto queue
         LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);

         SetEvent(m_hEvent); // signal the thread to wakeup and process it's message queue

         return S_OK;


     }


     void ThreadProcImpl()
     {

         // initialize thread if needed (e.g. call PeekMessage to initialize the message queue if you need one - in this implementation you don't)
         // signal back to the main thread we're off and running
         SetEvent(m_hThreadStarted);

         while (m_fNeedToExit == false)
         {
             bool fGotMsg = false;
             ThreadMessage msg;

             EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
                 if (m_queue.size > 0)
                 {
                     msg = m_queue.deque(); // remove the first message from the queue (if any)
                     fGotMsg = true;
                 }
             LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);

             // if the queue is empty, then wait for another message to come in
             if (fGotMsg == false)
             {
                 WaitForSingleObject(m_hEvent, INFINITE); // on return m_hEvent is auto-reset to unsignalled
                 continue; // back to top of while loop to deque
             }

             if (m_fNeedToExit)  // check exit condition
                 break;

             if (msg.type == YOUR_CODE_TO_QUIT)
                 break;


             // YOUR CODE TO HANDLE "ThreadMessage msg" goes here. (i.e. "do the work")

         }

         // thread cleanup code goes here (if any)
     }


     static DWORD __stdcall ThreadProc(void* pcontext)
     {
        CMyThread* pThis = (CMyThread*)pcontext;
        pThis->ThreadProcImpl();
        return 0;
     }


};
```

Comment: The issue was that my subclasses `InitInstance` function returned the same value as the superclass. `CWinThread::InitInstance` returns `FALSE`, which is interpreted as initialisation failing